# Service and Replication controller

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Is it possible to create a replication controller and service for a containerized application using one configuration file (yml/json)

Comment: Do you need to list several entities in one file? In this case you can simply separate them by using three dashes: "---", like in this example:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/8fd414537b5143ab039cb910590237cabf4af783/test/fixtures/doc-yaml/user-guide/multi-pod.yaml

Comment: Thanks that is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can have a normal yaml array of objects under List type, typical example can be found in the main repo like https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/master/hack/testdata/list.yaml

Comment: you can also just separate items with `----`